# A more formal way to say “is a good idea” in a science paper

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, formality

I would like to know how to say ¨is a good idea¨ in a formal setting.

After reading your comments, I add some context:
I have quoted a sentence from a soil scientist in a paper that I have submitted to a well-known International Journal.
Sentence:

> ***Increasing soil organic carbon (SOC) is a good idea in any situation to generate or maintain healthy soils.***
>   Lehmann, J., 2009. *Biological carbon sequestration must and can be a win-win approach*. An editorial comment 459–463. https://doi.org/10.1007/s10584-009-9695-y

A peer reviewer of my manuscript from that International Journal, in his suggested corrections, wrote:

> ‘Please, substitute “is a good idea”. You should use formal English’.

Comment: Why do you think that is not formal enough? What is the context?

Comment: ***holds promise*** is a particularly common (albeit cliched) usage in this area.

Comment: FF's suggestion is an excellent proposal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth's comment shows promise!

Comment: @FF I've never copied anyone's name on ELU before. I'm fighting the urge to snaffle OP's delightful moniker.

Comment: "Good idea" [is good enough for King Arthur](https://youtu.be/VZ42IMu7HIQ) (0:40); it should be good enough for you.

Comment: I would say it exactly as in the question. As with others, I fail to understand why it isn't appropriately formal.

Comment: The context you provide in the edited form of your question suggests that something like "is a sound practice" or even "is beneficial" might be a suitable replacement for "is a good idea."

Comment: I was just about to say exactly the same as @SvenYargs. Or "recommended". Although I don't see why they object to "good idea"; some people seem to think that academic writing has to sound more complicated than it is.

Comment: @JoseMAlvarezdelaPuente But, hang on: you are **quoting** someone. Is this a direct quote? You can't change someone else's words because a reviewer of _your_ paper doesn't like it. You could make it an indirect quote, but I think that rather defeats the point of quoting it. I think you should ignore this "correction" (and explain why if necessary/possible).

Comment: @JamesRandom the OP writes *"in a paper that I have submitted"* so I think the paper is his, and someone in a peer review suggested changing *"is a good idea"*. It seems a fair observation, if you're going to use the words "generate" instead of "grow" or "produce" and "maintain" instead of "keep", it makes sense to point out that the register of "good idea" is simplistic (not wrong) compared to the rest.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The OP said "I have quoted a sentence ..." and provided the reference to the source of the quotation. So I assumed the sentence is quoted from that paper. Unfortunately, the paper is behind a paywall so I can't access it. EDIT: the cited paper is available here: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/55ce/52f4926b30ea431a6e29173bf3202e78ad4d.pdf and the quoted sentence is from there. So the OP has no right to change it.

Comment: @JamesRandom I understand that *Please, substitute “is a good idea”. You should use formal English’.* is the quoted sentence from that review.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There is some confusion over the quoted sentence, which is: "Increasing soil organic carbon (SOC) is a good diea in any situation to generate or maintain healthy soils." Note that the reviewer is **not** reviewing the paper where the quoted sentence first appears, but another paper that is _quoting_ that paper.

Comment: I don't think a third party could even substitute an expression without having direct access to the original. The OP should clarify if the paper is his (he might be using a pseudonym username) or if he's merely interested from an English language point of view, which makes it a perfectly valid request. E.g. If I were that researcher what would I write instead of "is a good idea"?

Comment: @Mari-LouA As the paper with "good idea" was already published (in 2009) it is pretty clear that the reviewer comment applies to the paper that the OP is writing, and which quotes the older paper.

Comment: Trying to sound "more formal" than necessary is a [plague on academic writing](http://stevenpinker.com/files/pinker/files/why_academics_stink_at_writing.pdf).

Comment: I would use "desirable" as a formal alternative.  Increasing soil organic carbon (SOC) is desirable in any situation to ....

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you are you are **quoting** the following sentence from a previously published paper written by someone else:

> Increasing soil organic carbon (SOC) is a good idea in any situation to generate or maintain healthy soils.

If that is the case, then you cannot change someone else's words because a reviewer of *your* paper doesn't like it. You could make it an indirect quote, but I think that rather defeats the point of quoting it. I think you should ignore this "correction" (and explain why, if necessary/possible).

Comment: This, of course, pre-empts anything else that could be said in response to this question. It seems that the *heading* of the question has caused all other answerers to either overlook or misunderstand this aspect of it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the word choice is not ideal. Two words in particular come to mind:

1. **[advisable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/advisable)**: fit to be advised or done; prudent

   > Increasing soil organic carbon (SOC) is *advisable* in any situation to generate or maintain healthy soils.

(Note: prudent is also a good choice.)

2. **recommended**:

   > Increasing soil organic carbon (SOC) is *recommended* in any situation to generate or maintain healthy soils.

Comment: You beat me to it by few minutes. +1 for advisable.

Answer (score 1):

In a “formal” setting, a lot depends on the nature of the formality and the people being addressed. I’m guessing that the idea is good *to you*, but that you’re looking for a word that appeals to a specific audience you have in mind. Here are some guesses about what might work for an audience focused on *intellectual quality*:

- a **reasonable idea**,
- an **inspired idea**,
- a **clever idea**.

On the other hand, some audiences might be more interested in the idea’s *emotional appeal*, and prefer something along the following lines:

- an **attractive idea**,
- a **winning idea**,
- a **compelling idea**.

The key, though, is to use the terms of reference set by your audience. Doctors are different from city planners. Bankers and engineers have different world views and different ideas of “good”. Best of luck in your search for *le mot juste*.

Answer (score 0):

**splendid** idea

> Very good or satisfying; praiseworthy:

Comment: A phrase like "holds/has promise" sounds like weasel words to say "nice try but not really good enough". Certainly not as positive as "good/splendid idea".

Comment: @JamesRandom noted and edited

Comment: @Mitch  the OP has added context, still no attempt at research, but I've voted to reopen the question all the same. In order not to influence users negatively I deleted my criticisms aimed at the original question.

Answer (score 0):

First, yes, it should be confirmed that 'good' can sound informal in very formal or technical contexts. It is a very common word, Anglo-Saxon, and somewhat vague. Technical writing prefers Latinisms and more recent neologisms which tend not to be so vague.

But, note that this is an *editorial* and is passing judgment on a particular technological solution. There may very well be technical support for the judgement, but it is an opinionated editorial so the use of 'good' may be appropriate (but at least not to the one reviewer). As an editorial it is a bit of marketing; one can use vague managerialisms like 'robust' which sound fancy and technical but are really empty synonyms for 'good'.

To convert 'good idea', simply find less frequent and more technical terms:

- good: excellent/preferred/successful/robust etc.
- idea: solution/treatment/approach/technique/etc.

Note that a thesaurus won't necessarily be very good...um successful at suggesting things. Context often gives a better hint as to what could fit. And choosing word-for-word is not necessarily the best 'translation' to a different register.